# Get Python script to run binary each time

Tags: python

I am using a python script to run a command in the terminal.  I have a program in C, numgen, that is simply supposed to randomly generate numbers.  After compiling numgen I then simulate running numgen on different architectures.

The text to be input into the command line:

```
cmd= "~/simdir/build/ALPHA/gem5.opt ~/simdir/configs/example /se.py   ~/First/NumGen/numgen -o   "
```

I then use the following to run the command in a subshell

```
for x in range(5): //number of simulations
os.system(run)//run is cmd plus a string I created using a for loop because se.py requires an argument
```

I encounter a problem though.  After running everything I output relevant data about numgen to a file using result_file.write().  This would be fine except all the output in this new file is identical.  The numgen program is in C and is meant to generate random numbers.  It does that fine, and when I run the binary, ./numgen, in the terminal I get lists of random numbers.

Within the script, it seems os.system is not running the binary each time in the subshell.  Os.system runs the binary once in the beginning and prints out that same data for the rest of the simulations.  Does anyone know how I can get the data to be truly random?  I would like to have the binary be run before every simulation so the generated data can be different.  Is it possible to do this within a script?  I do have compilation flags and other text in the script, but I do not think those pertain to the problem like the above code does.

Essentially, os.system runs binary once for all the simulations.  I would like to know if it is possible to run the binary for each different simulation.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

EDIT 1- Full Script:

```
from random import * 
from array import *
import sys, string, os, subprocess, shlex, binascii, collections, operator 
import re
import subprocess


plaintext = array('B', [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]); 

loop = long(0); 
loop_max = long(1000); 
number = long(0); 
byte_index = 0; 

cmd = "~/simdir/build/ALPHA/gem5.opt ~/simdir/configs/example /se.py   --num-cpus=1 --caches --l2cache --cpu-type=timing --cacheline_size=64  --l1d_size=32kB --l1d_assoc=2 --l1i_size=32kB --l1i_assoc=4 --l2_size=1MB --l2_assoc=2  --max-checkpoints=200 -c ~/First/NumGen/numgen -o  " 


string="" 

Somekeywords = ['sim_freq','sim_ticks','host_mem_usage', 'system.cpu.numCycles', 'host_seconds',  'sim_insts' ]

table = [[0 for first in range(26)] for second in range(loop_max)]; #16 for plaintext bytes, 1 for ticks, 9 for L1D/L1I/L2 miss/hit/access
result =[[0 for first in range(26)] for second in range(loop_max)];

outfile = stats_text = open('Data.txt', 'w') 



stats_text=open('RelStat', 'w')

numb=10


for x in range(numb): 



    number=number+1
    outfile.write('%d\n' % number)

    run = ""
    string= ""
    final_str = ""

    for x in range(16): 
       plaintext[i] = randint(0, 255) 

    tmp = ""

    #Dec -> HEX -> Str
    for x in range(16):
        tmp = hex(plaintext[i])[2:] 
        if len(tmp)==1:
            tmp = "0"+tmp 

        string = string + tmp 


    run = cmd + string 


    subprocess.Popen(run, shell=True).wait() #Just changed this previously used os.system(run)

    stats_text = open('newdir/analysis.txt', 'r') 


    count = 0;
    for line in stats_text: 
        for index in range(3): 
            if Somekeywords[index] in line: 

                count = count + 1; #    
        line=re.sub('[^0-9]',' ', line) 
        outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write("\n")




                if count>10 and count<21: 
                    result_tmp = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b',line); 
                    print(loop);
                    result[loop][16+index] = int(result_tmp[0]);



    for i in range(16):
        result[loop][i] = plaintext[i];

    loop = loop + 1;

    if loop == loop_max:
        loop = 0;

        for i in range(loop_max):
            for j in range(26):
                final_str = final_str + str(result[i][j]) + ' '; 

outfile.write("\n")


outfile.close
```

EDIT 2 - Numgen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *of1;
    of1=fopen("Data.txt", "w");
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int z=0; z<16; z++)
    {
        int numgen=rand()%100;
        fprintf(of1, "%d ", numgen);
    }
    fclose(of1);
}
```

Just a quick program to generate a random number.  Also, the program is in C, not C++ as I previously stated.  I must have been compiling the .cpp with gcc and not notice.

Comment: How do you generate random numbers in C++? Do you use `seed` before generating random numbers?

Comment: I think you should run the `subprocess` module to run commands on the shell. It's more powerful compared to `os.system`. See this link for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: paste your full script here, especially how to you build `run`

Comment: @niyasc I have a random seed.  I am using srand.  Thanks

Comment: @Shubham Vasaikar Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately my problem still persists, but I will use subprocess module, particularly subprocess.Popen, instead of os.system for cases like this in the future.  Thanks

Comment: That is not the full script.

Comment: Try to use subprocess' `check_output`, it should work. I've used it in scenarios like this. Can't confirm for your case unless we can see your whole script and cpp build.

Comment: I have added the numgen, it is in C, not in C++ like I previously stated.  Sorry about that.  Also, this is the script I have been using.  I am not sure what could be missing.  If I am missing something crucial then maybe that is the source of my problem.  Thanks